# Why does state not update correctly when calling setState() multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When clicking the button, the text "second message" and "third message" should be added to the state through these functions:

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
    }

    addMessage() {
        this.props.addMessage('second message'); // This is ignored
        this.props.addMessage('third message');  // Only this message is added
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={this.addMessage}>Add text</button>
        )
    }
}
```

But only one of them is firing.

I created a simple snippet that shows the problem.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
 }
 
 addMessage() {
  this.props.addMessage('second message'); // This is ignored
  this.props.addMessage('third message');  // Only this message is added
 }
 
 render() {
  return(
   <button onClick={this.addMessage}>Add text</button>
  )
 }

}

class Messages extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 
 render() {
  return(
   <p>{this.props.message}</p>
  )
 }

}

class App extends React.Component {
 
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   messages: [{
    text: 'first message'
   }]
  }
  this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
 }
 
 addMessage(message) {
  let messages = this.state.messages.slice();
  messages.push({text:message});
  this.setState({messages: messages});
 }
 
 render() {
  let messages = [];
  this.state.messages.forEach((message) => {
   messages.push(<Messages message={message.text}></Messages>);
  });
  return(
   <div>
    {messages}
    <Button addMessage={this.addMessage} />
   </div>
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### State Updates May Be Asynchronous

Quoted from the [reactjs docs about state updates](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, **you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state**.

Your second call to `addMessage()` uses `this.state` to set the new state. But because `setState()` is asynchronous the state my not have been updated yet which leads to your second call overriding your first one:

```js
addMessage(message) {

    // here you access this.state which hasn't been updated yet in your second call
    let messages = this.state.messages.slice();

    messages.push({text: message});
    this.setState({messages: messages});
}
```

> To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function
>   rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state
>   as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied
>   as the second argument:

Use an arrow function that gets passed the previous state including changes of preceding calls to `setState()`to calculate the new state. That will fix your issue.

Using es6 spread syntax:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    messages: [...prevState.messages, {text: message}]
}));
```

Using `slice()`:

```js
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    let messages = prevState.messages.slice();
    messages.push({text:message});
    return {messages};
});
```